# How do I design the CardView so its next to each other?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

Hello! as the title suggest, I'm trying to put those two CardViews next to each other. Is it possible to do so. Currently this is what my xml looks like. Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/homeBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/layout_user_information"

        android:weightSum="4"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/home_image"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/userboy"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id = "@+id/home_username"
                android:text = "Username"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </TextView>


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view_booking"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_booking" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
                    android:text="Booking" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_history"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_history"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:text="History"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have already `match_parent` for both layout width and height for the first LinearLayout. but no luck there. Is there any way I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrap the both layout that contains CardView with another linear Layout with

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

the whole code will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/homeBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Home">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_booking"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_booking" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
                        android:text="Booking" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view_history"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="50dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home_history" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsbold"
                        android:text="History" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: okay it worked! but now the elements are all messed up. here, https://imgur.com/DI3yLRI

Comment: remove the android:weightSum="4"

Comment: got it! its getting close! is there a way to fix the inconsistencies? https://imgur.com/a/XYy1UeA

Comment: use android:layout_weight="1" in linear layout or give them a fixed width

Comment: Are you sure you have added the android:layout_weight="1 to all layout which have cardview or you can also give the cardview specifc width

Comment: oh my god, I got it! I didn't apply it on the cardview previously. Thank you so much, you kind soul. I appreciate ittt

Comment: Thanks for compliment and don't forget to accept the answer if its helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a linear layout with orientation = "horizontal" and have the card view placed under it